# RTL List in J2ME

Tags: java-me, right-to-left

How can I make my J2ME List goes from right to left?

I know the StringItem has the setLayout function which can be used to achieve this, but List can only get plain Strings (right?)... How can I do this?

Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SetLayout(Item.LAYOUT_RIGHT);
```

Comment: "SetLayout" should be invoked on which object? it's not member of "List" nor of MIDlet...